# Connection timed out error with MQTT connection with Raspberry Pi and ESP8266

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

When wanting to connect my raspberry pi to my esp8266 wirelessly through MQTT it gives a connection timed out error and I am not sure why. I have surfed throughout the internet and could not find anything that would help. As well as that I am not an expert programmer.

Comment: Which MQTT broker are you running? Is it using port 1883 (plain MQTT), 8883 (MQTT+TLS) or 9001 (MQTT+websockets)?

Comment: Are you sure both devices are communicating in general (i.e. wifi is set up properly on both devices)?  What MQTT client are you using on the ESP8266?

Comment: I am using port 1883 and wifi is a little bit weak will this totally destroy the communication my node mcu (esp8266) is my client